# Как проверить аггрегированное значения группы?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

В наборе данных есть такой DataFrame:

```
класс    процент    доп_инфа
первый     60        впрвер
первый     40        рверв
второй     50        пыкпыевн
второй     20        ервер
третий     80        кнукнф
третий     10        венврке
```

Необходимо узнать, какие классы НЕ имеют сумму 100. В моём случае - это второй и третий. Таким образом, ответом должен быть:

```
Out[]: 
класс      процент
второй     70
третий     90
```

Попытался сделать вот так, но выводит полностью DataFrame со значениями NaN:

```
sm = data[data.groupby('класс').sum()]
data.where(sm != 100)
```

Comment: А зачем вы делаете так: `data[data.groupby('класс').sum()]` а не смотрите просто результат `data.groupby('класс').sum()`? По-моему из-за этого ерунда получается

Comment: @CrazyElf, у меня свыше 1000 строк в dataframe и все подряд проверять на правильность будет долго по времени

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в pandas не разбираюсь:

```
dict_ = {}
for class_, procent in zip(data["класс"], data["процент"]):
    try:
        dict_[class_] +=procent
    except:
        dict_[class_] = procent

for class_, procent in dict_.items():
    if procent == 100:
        continue
    print(class_, procent)
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Вариант 1

группируем, суммируем, фильтруем по сумме:

```
res = df.groupby("класс")["процент"].sum().reset_index().query("процент != 100")
```

#### Вариант 2

Сначала получаем индексы строк, для которых сумма в столбце `процент` не равна `100`. Затем фильтруем, группируем и суммируем:

```
idx = df.groupby("класс")["процент"].filter(lambda x: x.sum() != 100).index
res = df.loc[idx].groupby("класс")["процент"].sum().reset_index()
```

---

#### Результат:

```
In [13]: res
Out[13]:
    класс  процент
0  второй       70
1  третий       90
```

Comment: @Danis ответил первее, но ваши способы тоже хороши. Только в первом варианте у меня неправильно индекс выводится. Должен быть 0, а там 79. Спасибо за ответ

Comment: @EUG217, если хотите, чтобы в результате индекс был непрерывным и начинался с нуля сделайте так: `res.reset_index(drop=True)`